# javascript: popup a window and save its html code

Tags: javascript, popup

Not sure if this is even possible but... from one.html can I popup a window (for example to somesite.com/index.html) and save all the HTML in a hidden field in one.html?

Thanks!

Comment: **ALL** the html, it depends how big is the HTML in the second page

Comment: nevermind, missread question!

Comment: @gdoron, the second page's html is quite big but not overly big. It's fine if the JS dumps all the html into a textarea too... I just need the code from the popup window then I will be closing the popup window anyway.

Comment: Are both pages on the same domain?

Comment: "Are both pages on the same domain?" - unfortunately no :(

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent you from getting very far. You'll probably have to setup a server-side script to download the page and your JS gets it from that. (like a proxy)

Comment: Then your only chance is using jsonp with a well-supported ajax response. You can't go scraping other domains secretly, this is a security risk. How would you like some web site visiting Facebook and learning all your friends, or reading your Google email, without your knowledge?

Comment: But its a public page that I have access to (after I give my user/pass)... when I "popup" it, it opens without a problem, I just need to get all the html from that popup into the first window :(  
Not possible?

Comment: @sachleen or if you have control over _somesite.com_, set up [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this through a 'popup' will cause all sorts of exceptions since browsers have rules against cross-domain anything. They try to prevent things like javascript trying to access the document on the other side, there's just too many hackers which will go 'oh yay another exploit!'.

If you're looking for a way to load the HTML into an element on your page, I recommend using AJAX. To use a browser's built-in ajax, you can use the XMLHttpRequest object. The steps for that would be first create the object, then tell it what you want to fetch and how, then fetch it, then read the data.

Here's an example:

```
// Create the object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Open page
xhr.open( 'GET', '/index.html', true );
// Register your events
xhr.onsuccess = function() {
    // awesome, it loaded!
    destination.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
   // the page denied my request because: e
};
// send any data if you want, or just execute the request
xhr.send( myData || null );
```

Where destination would be something like:

```
// jQuery version:
var destination = $( 'textarea#content-holder' );
// Equivalent to:
var destination = (function(tag, id) {
    var elms = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for ( i = 0; i < elms.length; i++ ) {
        if ( elms[i].id === id ) return elms[i];
    }
    return undefined;
})('textarea', 'content-holder');
```

On the other hand, an awesome library with ajax support is jQuery, you can get it at http://jquery.com/. The main reason I recommend that for ajax is it has a few different hacks and patches for different types of ajax requests, it's really neat and you can avoid a lot of pain through it.

To load what you were trying, your code would look like this:

```
$( destination ).load( '/index.html', function() {
    // do stuff after it's been loaded
);
```

Another really cool thing jQuery will let you do is load a specific part of the page from 'index.html', that is through the standard queries. For example, let's say you wanted to load the markup only from an element with the class 'load-me', you should do this:

```
$( destination ).load( '/index.html .load-me', function() {
    // after load stuff
);
```

One way to bypass the cross-domain limit completely is using cURL, but that will require some PHP. Here's a quick example:

In /ajax.php write:

```
<?php
    if ( ! $_POST['ajax'] ) die();

    // this doesn't consider errors
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['url']);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

In your javascript write:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Open the script
xhr.open( 'POST', '/ajax.php', true);
// Register your events
xhr.onsuccess = function() {
    // awesome, it loaded!
    destination.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
   // the page denied my request because: e
};
xhr.send( { 'ajax':'true', 'url':'http://somesite.com/index.html' } );
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$( destination ).load( '/ajax.php', {ajax:true,url:'http://somesite.com/indexhtml'}, function() {
    // awesome, it loaded!
} );
```

Things to consider:
- With AJAX you still can't make cross-domain requests, there's ways, but there's no perfect ways. (With the XMLHttpRequest, you will have to find and write the hacks yourself

- Without jQuery it will be difficult to parse the loaded data. For instance, if you're trying to grab a specific element I hope you have mad RegExp skills.
- Different browsers have different implementations of ajax. In IE, the constructor is ActiveXObject.Create('XMLHttpRequest'). Note: all this is part of jQuery.

Hope you figure things out! XD

Answer (score 0):

If the popup is on the same domain you can write this code in the popup window:

```
opener.document.getElementById('hidden').value = "the value you want";
```

Comment: I inferred the popup page would be on a different domain, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: @sachleen, well.. I thought it's obvious it has to be... I added your comment to avoid confusing.

Comment: It's only obvious if you know about it.

Comment: @sachleen and if you think about it for a second... of course the popup can't touch windows of different domains, it'll be a security problem. well... anyway, I saw his comment and this is the case so... it's impossible.